# BigQuery - Dimension table design for DataWarehouse?

Tags: google-bigquery, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I have noticed that BigQuery is good for maintaining historical data, but it is not as performant when making individual record updates.

For historical data, how effective is it to maintain a Dimensional table in BigQuery in the "dimension-and-fact paradigm"? I want to use this paradigm only in cases when the dimension data is periodically fully refreshed, since the dimension table cannot contain duplicate keys and BigQuery is not performant with record level updates.

What other approaches can I use to maintain a dimension table? Bigtable comes to mind, but is this a good application for it?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the size of your "facts" and "dimensions" in your "Fact" and "Dimension" tables, and how you expect to relate the two, Bigtable may be a good solution as well.

Given that a Bigtable is well-suited to both point writes and batch ingest, you may find that maintaining very granular data in your "Fact" table would be easy to do, and fast to interact with at the application level.

- For example, if you were focused on retail, your "Facts" table could use a Bigtable table a historical log for customer purchases, with rows containing information about purchases from customers.

Depending on the size of the "Dimensions" table, it may also be suited for Bigtable, especially if fast point updates are required.

- Pulling on retail again, your "Dimensions" table could be a Bigtable table containing stock room availability describing how many items of a type exist.

One important caveat is that Bigtable does not support secondary indices: there would be no way in your query to do a join between these two Bigtable tables, you would need to reduce the values on the application side.

For more information, see the [Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable) docs!

Answer (score 1):

For BigQuery it is [better](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-input#denormalize_data_whenever_possible) to keep the data denormalized. As it is columnar storage, performance will not be affected when using large amounts of data. Here you can review on [managing](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/bigquery-data-warehouse#managing_data) data in BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks. I had read that. But just wanted to know any other different options out there.

Comment: Note that if you do end up exploring Bigtable as a storage option, BigQuery also has federated query support for querying Bigtable:

https://icharts.net/blog/press-and-news/google-federated-querying-icharts